# How to test for a redirect in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, mojolicious

I want to test a page with a form which, when submitted, will redirect to the resulting page for the submitted item.

My Mojolicious controller contains:

```
sub submit_new {
    my $self = shift;

    my $new = $self->db->resultset('Item')->new( {
        title       => $self->param('title'),
        description => $self->param('description'),
    } );
    $new->insert;

    # show the newly submitted item
    my $id = $new->id;
    $self->redirect_to("/items/$id");
}
```

The test script for this controller contains:

```
use Test::More;
use Test::Mojo;

my $t = Test::Mojo->new('MyApp');

my $tx = $t->ua->build_form_tx('/items/new/submit' => $data);
$tx->req->method('POST');
$t->tx( $t->ua->start($tx) )
  ->status_is(302);
```

My issue is that it stops with the `302` status. How do I proceed with the redirect so I can verify the resulting item page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the matching setting from Mojo::UserAgent:

```
$t->ua->max_redirects(10)
```

Also, you don't need to build the form post manually:

```
$t->post_form_ok('/items/new/submit' => $data)->status_is(...);
```

Reference:

- http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Test/Mojo#ua
- http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent#max_redirects
- http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Test/Mojo#post_form_ok

Comment: *post_form_ok* seems not to exist any more - or has just the syntax changed?

Comment: Indeed; post_form used to exist in Mojo::UserAgent as well. They've been merged into post, so the new usage would be: $t->post_ok($url => form => $data);

Answer (score 1):

You could also (and probably should) test the content of the landing page to which the successful login has redirected :

```
my $tm = '' ; # the test message for each test
my $t = Test::Mojo->new('Qto');
$t->ua->max_redirects(10);
my $app = 'foobar';
my $url = '/' . $db_name . '/login' ;

 $tm = "a successfull result redirects to the home page";
 my $tx = $t->ua->post( $url => 'form'  => {'email' =>'test.user@gmail.com', 'pass' => 'secret'});
 ok ( $tx->result->dom->all_text =~ "$app home" , $tm );
```

[the docs for how-to get the content with mojo dom](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SRI/Mojolicious-7.73/lib/Mojolicious/Guides/Testing.pod)

[the mojo dom selector syntax doc link](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#selector)

[an example testing script with login testing](https://github.com/YordanGeorgiev/qto/blob/v0.6.7/src/perl/qto/t/lib/Qto/Controller/TestLogin.pl)